# In which point compiler needs to reorder executions for optimization?

Tags: multithreading, mutex, semaphore, compiler-optimization, memory-barriers

I was checking about mutexes, semaphores, spin_locks memory barriers etc. and I just come up to `execution reorder` thing. I read something about at wiki but it really doesn't make any sense to me, reordering execution for optimization concern ? Isn't that break the code ? What is the restrictions. It says in this wiki page [Java Memory Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model)

> On modern platforms, code is frequently not executed in the order it was written. It is reordered by the compiler, the processor and the memory subsystem to achieve maximum performance. On multiprocessor architectures, individual processors may have their own local caches that are out of sync with main memory.

So specifically multi-threaded concept it brings performance but it makes your program unstable, or incosistent. You have to be extremely careful. So isn't this over complexity for the specific performance reasons, and code reordering it looks scary.

Comment: The compiler provides some guarantees such as the code will appear as it was executed in order if it was single-threaded. However, if your program is multithreaded, it's your job to make sure that your ordering is satisfied (with the use of memory barriers, locks, signals, etc.).

Comment: You should not be scared of this stuff if you ever want to get a job. You need to do a lot of reading on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As good scenario for reordering consider the following:

```
A = B / C; => read B, C + compute + write to A
D = E + F; => read E, F + compute + write to D
```

which translates as:

```
read B, C
compute B/C
write result to A
read E, F
compute E+F
write result to D
```

can be reordered as:

```
read B, C, E, F ==> force reads as soon as possible
compute B / C => slow operation (could do something usefull such as read E, F in the meanwhile)
compute E + F
write A, write D => defer writes as late as possible
```

This does not break the single threaded ordering guarantee and achieves better execution throughput.

Also, [here](http://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/) the concepts are pretty good described.

Comment: A real code and example would suit the answer better.

Comment: So what about `A = B / C; D = E + A;` ? It looks like there is over over complexity for the compiler. Is the compiler still go for the optimization ?

Comment: Most likely, yes. But it depends on a number of factors here since there are 2 types of reorderings: compiler and CPU-based. So, even if the compiler won't reorder it, the CPU will.

Comment: I understand, so do you know any good article or pdf which clarifies cpu based optimization and the compiler based optimization, I also check google but it would be super if do you know qualified one.

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/course/comparch: highly recommended on CPU as a whole and CPU reorderings. And http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Architecture-Fifth-Edition-Quantitative/dp/012383872X.

Comment: Another thing to read about are memory barriers/fences since these are more compiler-oriented (http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.ro/2011/07/memory-barriersfences.html)

Comment: @TamasIonut thanks for the suggestions, I'll focus them.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't that break the code ?

Optimizations are restricted to changes that do not violate the guarantees that the language makes. The key point is that many languages do not fully specify behavior. When two threads execute `x = 1` and `x = 2` the result is *not* fully specified.

> So isn't this over complexity for the specific performance reasons, and code reordering it looks scary.

Whether it's overly or not overly complicated depends on your goals. Some languages are extremely safe, others are very loose. All languages give you tools to write safe programs. The tools vary as well as the difficulty to make it work. Also, performance varies.

Comment: hmm, so the performance reason is threatening to programmer, it is something an heavy weight on programmer's shoulder. I have no detailed information what is the rules of optimization. I may look the concept as it is so scary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the code which is likely to be reordered:

```
extern bool b;
extern int x;
extern int y;
extern int z;

void foo() {
  z = x;
  if (b)
    y = x;

}
```

The alleged idea is following: first set global `z` to something, and if `b` is set, set `y` as well. It is assumed that there is another thread, which is somehow querying `z`, and once it becomes what it wants, it sets `b` - thus allowing `foo()` to assign `y`.

This code, of course, has multiple issues, but I will focus on reordering. The code produces following assembly:

```
foo():
        cmpb    $0, b(%rip)
        movl    x(%rip), %eax
        movl    %eax, z(%rip)
        je      .L1
        movl    %eax, y(%rip)
.L1:
        rep ret
```

As you see, b is checked first! than `x` is copied to `z`, and than jump is performed. Execution has been reordered - boolean flag is checked before the assignment is done, and the whole idea is broken. (it would be broken anyways, so this example is just a reordering illustration).

Comment: This just shows that the compiler may reorder operations but doesn't answer any of the posed questions. The questions are actually too general involving compilers, architectures, and memory subsystems and any good answer would have to be very long.

Comment: @HadiBrais, the only clear question I was able to see in the post is one from the header: "*In which point compiler needs to reorder executions for optimization?*". Tried answering it.